# Can I use static classes in template files?

Tags: theming

Can I reference data as:

```
<?php print t(OgNotifyAttendHelper::findWelcomeName($user)); ?>
```

The class is included in the .info file for a module, and this template is accessed via hook_theme from a parent module (this is a submodule).

Comment: Why dont you try it ?

Comment: Behaviour is inconsistent. Perhaps someone knows that class autoloader is not good in this context, or can say that it does work and I will persist.

Comment: As a side note, your use of t() is incorrect, see [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7). It should be something like t('@name', array('@name' => OgNotifyAttendHelper::findWelcomeName($user))) I try to keep any function/method calls out of template files, and rather do the work using a preprocess function and pass a plain variable into the template file. Drupal 8 is using twig so from that stage onwards it wouldn't be possible to do function calls in a template file, as far as I know. I'm sure it can be done though. What is the inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for the t() note. It isn't really translatable. Having it xss safe could be a good idea. I have now just passed the static as a variable. The code would work happily on some servers and sometimes but at other times come up with function not found errors.